# How to make git change submodule commit # through "git apply"

Tags: git

I have a situation where I have to apply Git changes by using patch files instead of checkouts. The project has a submodule.

What I am trying to achieve is best explained through an example:

- Situation: base at commit `#B1`, submodule at commit `#S1`, everything clean.
- Submodule is changed, committed as `#S2`.
- I run `git diff > file.patch`. The file looks like:

`diff --git a/submodule b/submodule
index S1..S2 160000
--- a/submodule
+++ b/submodule
@@ -1 +1 @@
-Subproject commit S1
+Subproject commit S2`

- Someone else still has the repo in the starting situation: base @ `#B1`, submodule @ `#S1`.
- He/she applies my patch using `git apply file.patch`.
- Git does not do anything to their submodule. It only throws the following warning:
  `warning: unable to rmdir submodule: Directory not empty`

What I expected, is that the tracking info for the submodule would be updated: in other words, I expected that running `git status` after this series of steps would show: `modified:   submodule (new commits)`, and that I could then pull its changes with `git submodule update`.

I have tried various combinations of arguments and diff formats, but none of them result in `git apply` being able to get the submodule into the desired state.

Is it possible in `git` to change the tracking state for submodules by applying patch files?

---

FYI, the real background for this is that I'm using Phabricator and `arc`, and noticed that `arc patch` nor `arc land` are able to take submodules into account - AFAIK that is because of exactly this reason: the tool assumes `git` will take care of everything but it doesn't.

Comment: So I misunderstood you question. Then I don't think it's possible to apply this very patch because it doesn't have necessary data. You can push the main repo and submodule so that he/she can pull them.

Comment: But the patch has the necessary data right? The diff shows exactly what commit of the submodule is being tracked by the main repo. I didn't expect `git apply` to actually check that code out in the submodule, but I did expect it to make the submodule "dirty". To be clear: yes, in this workflow I would expect users to push the submodule commit upstream so that other users can fetch them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[The `git apply` documentation](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-apply.html) describes precisely how submodule patches are applied (or not):

> ### SUBMODULES
>
> If the patch contains any changes to submodules then *git apply* treats these changes as follows.
>
> If `--index` is specified (explicitly or implicitly), then the submodule commits must match the index exactly for the patch to apply. If any of the submodules are checked-out, then these check-outs are completely ignored, i.e., they are not required to be up to date or clean and they are not updated.
>
> If `--index` is not specified, then the submodule commits in the patch are ignored and only the absence or presence of the corresponding subdirectory is checked and (if possible) updated.

Note that `-3`(also spelled `--3way`) implies `--index`, and in general, for applying patches generated by `git format-patch`, you might want `-3`.